# Snort&Suricata content replacement rule

Tags: network, ids, tcp, snort

I have to deal with Surikata IDS and its snort-compatible ruleset.
Partially I need it in IPS mode for doing output traffic modifications. For now my "modifications" looks like this:

```
...
pass tcp 192.168.1.77 any -> any any (content:"apache"; nocase; replace:"------"; sid:102; )
pass tcp 192.168.1.77 any -> any any (content:"apache"; nocase; replace:"------"; sid:103; )
pass tcp 192.168.1.77 any -> any any (content:"apache"; nocase; replace:"------"; sid:104; )
pass tcp 192.168.1.77 any -> any any (content:"apache"; nocase; replace:"------"; sid:105; )
pass tcp 192.168.1.77 any -> any any (content:"apache"; nocase; replace:"------"; sid:106; )
pass tcp 192.168.1.77 any -> any any (content:"apache"; nocase; replace:"------"; sid:107; )
pass tcp 192.168.1.77 any -> any any (content:"apache"; nocase; replace:"------"; sid:108; )
pass tcp 192.168.1.77 any -> any any (content:"apache"; nocase; replace:"------"; sid:109; )
pass tcp 192.168.1.77 any -> any any (content:"apache"; nocase; replace:"------"; sid:110; )
pass tcp 192.168.1.77 any -> any any (content:"apache"; nocase; replace:"------"; sid:111; )
pass tcp 192.168.1.77 any -> any any (content:"apache"; nocase; replace:"------"; sid:112; )
pass tcp 192.168.1.77 any -> any any (content:"apache"; nocase; replace:"------"; sid:113; )
...
```

...which is awful. Because suricata replaces just the first occurence of "content" in tcp packet. Is there any way to avoid this bunch of identical rules?

P.S
As usual, I guess, I use NFQ to get relevant packets.